# How to create a partially modifiable binary file format?

Tags: data-structures, binary, filesystems, binaryfiles

I'm creating my custom binary file extension.

I use the RIFF standard for encoding data. And it seems to work pretty well.

But there are some additional requirements:

1. Binary files could be large up to 500 MB.
2. Real-time saving data into the binary file in intervals when data on the application has changed.
3. Application could run on the browser.

The problem I face is when I want to save data it needs to read everything from memory and rewrite the whole binary file.

This won't be a problem when data is small. But when it's getting larger, the Real-time saving feature seems to be unscalable.

So main requirement of this binary file could be:

1. Able to partially read the binary file (Cause file is huge)
2. Able to partially write changed data into the file without rewriting the whole file.
3. Streaming protocol like .m3u8 is not an option, We can't split it into chunks and point it using separate URLs.

Any guidance on how to design a binary file system that scales in this scenario?

Comment: **This is operating system specific and processor specific**. Are you allowed, or did you try, to use [sqlite](https://sqlite.org), GNU [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), [ReDis](https://redis.io/), [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org) or to study and borrow from their open source code ? And you probably are not designing a file system like [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). If you do, budget many months of work and see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/)

Comment: BTW, a 500Mb file is not that big. On most computers it fits inside RAM.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As I mentioned, I'm working in the browser. And I don't think writing 500MB every 5 seconds is a very good idea.

Comment: I agree with you. You could write your browser extension or plugin which would use [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), especially with open source browsers like [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I didn't look into those lib yet, that's very interesting.

Comment: You could also write your browser extension (preferably open source) or plugin generating specialized code using   [ASMjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) and partial evaluation techniques

Comment: How hard realtime is your application? What happens on timeouts or execution time above one second?

Comment: `Timeout above one second` I think that's compromisable for me.

Comment: `ASMjit` `Ext4`. Those are topics I never touched it before.

Comment: Just have an idea come up in my head.
Do you have any idea how those large file extensions like .blend .fcpx file are managed? As far as I looked into it's a kind of directory-based file. But I've no idea about the topic.

Comment: My recommendation is to use only open source software (and contribute to some of them)

Comment: Hmmm... .blend or .fcpx are Blender and FinalCut file extensions. Has nothing to do with Windows or Linux. And I think file extension design is an application layer so it should be OS independent and shouldn't have anything to do with the OS level either.

Comment: And I think binary file design also has nothing to do with open-source software. It's about data structure IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer from a random user that has been deleted here.
It seems great to me.
You can claim your answer back and I'll delete this one.

He said:
If we design the file to be support addition then we able to add whatever data we want without needing to rewrite the whole file.

---

This idea gives me a very great starting point.

So I can append more and more changes at the end of the file.
Then obsolete old chunks of data in the middle of the file.
I can then reuse these obsolete data slots later if I want to.

The downside is that I need to clean up the obsolete slot when I have a chance to rewrite the whole file.